# Adding new template folder in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Say I have the following folder structure

```
mysite
    - mysite
         - templates
    - books
         - templates
    - contact
         - templates
```

And I have the following in my settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

How would I configure the site to look in the templates folder of any sub directory? For example, say I wanted to add another folder to my existing 3 (mysite, books, contact) called "test". I would want the site to automatically know to search in "test/templates".

I am wondering if it is as simple as:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'mysite/templates').replace('\\','/'),
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'books/templates').replace('\\','/'),
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'contact/templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

To me, that looks like it would point to "/mysite/books/templates" not "/books/templates"

Comment: If 2 templates with same name exists in different template folders then only first one will be picked. How will you resolve that? So it is better to make folders inside the `mysite/templates` folder & reference the templates by full path.

Comment: Oh Ok I see. I was hoping to set the ROOT_URL to be something like "/site" and then I could say "ROOT_URL/books/templates", but instead the url is "/site/mysite", which makes things tricky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this:

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    )

And then i put all my templates under the templates folder (which is under the same directory as manage.py). This way i can find all the templates for my project in the same place.

```
+templates
-app1 templates
-app2 templates
```

When i need to access a template i just use 'app1/my_template.html'.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is the best way to do it. Less chance of any issues.